# count number of points in line interval

Tags: c++

I encountered a problem that requires the program to count the number of points within an interval. This problem provides a large amount of unsorted points, and lo,hi(restriction lo<=hi), and it aims to enumerate the points within [lo,hi]. The problem is that although my code is correct, it is too time-consuming to finish within given time (2200ms). My code can finish this mission in O(n). I would like to ask if there are any faster methods.

```
 int n,m,c,lo,hi;
    cin>>n>>m;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    cin>>lo>>hi;
    c=0;
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(arr[j]<=hi&&lo<=arr[j])c++;
    }
    cout<<c<<endl;
```

Comment: 1) No, I don't think there is a method faster than O(n), 2) is this an online coding contest? 3) Do you have reason to believe that a solution better than O(n) exists?

Comment: You get judged even on the time it takes to read in the input? I'm sure the processing time itself is not very large.

Comment: If the input is uniformly distributed, you could perhaps use a hash table to store counts of encountered ints as they are read in. Afterwards, you could check the hash table for counts for every integer between low and high.

Comment: there's no way to make it faster than O(N) as you need to read all the data which is already O(N).

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to solve this problem in less than `O(n)` time, because you *must* consider all inputs at least once.

However, you might be able to reduce the constant factor of `n` — have you consider storing a set of `(start, end)` intervals, rather than a simple array? What is the input size which causes this to be slow?

**Edit:** upon further testing, it seems the bottleneck is actually the use of `cin` to read numbers.

Try replacing every instance of `cin >> x;` with `scanf("%d", &x);` — for me, this brings the runtime down to about 0.08 seconds.

Comment: The input restrictions are 0<=lo,hi<10^7 and all the points within [0,10^7] and n<5*10^5

Comment: I just ran your program against 500,000 lines of input (random numbers). It seems to take about 1.2 seconds to run, which is quite reasonable. (In fact, it seems most of the time is spent reading the input!)

Comment: @jombo Yeah, seems like `scanf` is much faster here. Updated my answer.

Comment: `cin` shouldn't be that much slower than `scanf` (in fact, it can conceivably be faster since the type of the target is known at compile time, where `scanf` is runtime format string parsing). I suspect the speed discrepancy is due to C++ `iostream` syncing with C `stdio` by default (making them interoperate correctly, but preventing C++ from operating even remotely efficiently). [Running `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` at the top of your `main`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) to disable this synchronization would likely eliminate most of the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it faster than `O(N)` only if you need to do lookups more than once on the same data set:

1. Sort the array or its copy. For lookup you can use binary search -  which is O(log<sub>2</sub> N) complex.
2. Instead of flat array to use something like binary tree, lookup complexity will be as in #1.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the gist of what you're saying, but sorting takes time. At least O(n) for an integer sort. Creating a binary tree will take O(n log n). Sure, lookups afterwards will be cheap, but the data is not already sorted upon receipt. Edit: Plus the time taken to read all N elements is apparently counted.

Comment: Sorting takes time, indeed. But as I said, it makes sense to do sorting only if you need to do lookups more than once - like if that input set is more or less static. So you can sort it once, cache sorted set and do many cheap lookups. If number of lookups will be more than log2(N) you clearly will get results faster on sorted cache.